# Problem with implementing Sort in Spring Data (Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I need to do the following sql query using spring data api:

```
Select * from TagTest where tagName = "water temperature" Order by timestamp desc;
```

I came up with the query:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("tagName").is("water temperature"));
```

I defined `Sort` as:

```
query.sort().on("timestamp", Order.DESCENDING);
```

and the using mongoTemplate do `findOne()` like:

```
mongoTemplate.findOne(Collection, query, MongoTag.class);
```

But I cannot find a way to apply the sort to retrieve results in `findOne`. 
Is the approach correct? Please let me know the correct approach in case I am wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: is `mongoTemplate.findOne(Collection, query, MongoTag.class);` in a for loop and are you adding it to an ArrayList or an Array?
if not, then you won't be able to sort from 1 single returned value.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Mongo isn't a SQL database, so you will never be running any SQL on it. I recommend spending some time on the Mongo command line to familiarise yourself with the way querying for documents works in Mongo - it's very different to SQL in some ways, exactly the same in others. I'd also have a read of the Mongo documentation, which is pretty good: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home.

Secondly, looking at the 'SQL' query you're aiming for, it looks like you want all the TestTags, not just one. `findOne` does just what it says - returns a single record. You probably want to use `find` instead.

A good place to start is probably to work out what you'd be running on the mongo command line and work from there.

You can't use `findOne` and sort together, but you should be able to use `findAll` and sort together. And if you only want one result, you can add a limit to the query: `query.limit(1)` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running a **findOne** and then trying to **sort** it? Have you tried that in traditional SQL? It does not make sense. Otherwise you are on the right path. Try the following, it worked for me:

```
public List<Person> listPersons() {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.limit(MAX_ROWS)
        .sort().on("dateCreated", Order.ASCENDING);

    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this :

```
public List<Person> listPersons() {
Criteria criteria=Criteria.where("tagName").is("water temperature"));
Query query = new Query();
query.addcriteria(criteria);
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,"dateCreated")) ;   

return mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
}
```

is the response to your question i think.